# Under divine simplicity, how can God do anything?

Tags: catholicism, nature-of-god, creation, divine-simplicity, immutability

The consequence of divine simplicity is that God is being subsisting and can only be immutable.

If so how does God do anything? Or how did he create?

Comment: Why does His divine simplicity pose a problem for His ability to create?

Comment: I can see how immutability poses a question to God deciding to create (if he was happy and content without creating a universe what changed such that he deemed to create one?) but I'm not also not too sure how simplicity connects to the question of creating. Could you please [edit] to clarify?

Comment: How can a immutable God basically not be a frozen rock?

Comment: Ah I see. How can God be unchanging and yet still do action (which implies a change in God’s action, so a change in God). Basically, I would make a distinction between God’s nature and action. Actions don’t change nature. Actions proceed from nature.

Comment: @johnyman Again you're focusing on God's immutability. Would it be okay to edit the question to just ask about immutability rather than divine simplicity?

Comment: One thing only adds confusion: **sin**. God is without confusion or division. Thus he is divinely simple.

Comment: What do you understand "divine simplicity" to be?

Comment: You are taking too narrow a view of "immutability". It means God doesn't change his nature, not that he never does anything. Doing something does not change his nature.

Answer (score 1):

Per St. Thomas Aquinas (and Aristotle), things have actual states and potential states. God, per Aquinas, has actual state but no potential (https://www.scotthambrick.com/article/1081/). This makes Him immutable. This is part of divine simplicity (https://pintswithaquinas.com/what-is-divine-simplicity/).

Other, contingent beings have both actual and potential traits. In order to create change in a contingent being, something has to activate that potential. Ultimately every potential that's activated must result from some cause that is not itself caused by something else -- like if you're pushing something with a stick, the motion of the stick is caused by the motion of your hand is caused by the contraction of your muscles, etc. If there's no prime cause, there's no motion. So there *has* to be an ultimate cause that is itself not contingent, that is not having its potential actualized by something. "This," Aquinas says, "everyone understands to be God" ([https://home.csulb.edu/~cwallis/100/st2.html](https://home.csulb.edu/%7Ecwallis/100/st2.html)).

I wouldn't know how to address a perceived contradiction between being immutable Oneself and causing change in other things, because like other commenters and AFAIK Aquinas I don't see the contradiction, but it's clear Aquinas thinks that every change in our world *requires* a simple and immutable Cause.

Comment: is God's one single eternal act the cause of multiple acts and things?Vasubandhu criticizes this,and ibn sina uses it to logically presuppose emanationism.how are they wrong?

Comment: I'm not aware, in Christianity, of God having "one single eternal act." If there were such a thing, what would it be? The Incarnation? In the Bible, there are multiple divine acts, from Creation of the universe to the parting of the Red Sea to the gifts of the Spirit in Corinthians.